# Android Package Name, Do i need a domain or not?

Tags: android, package

I'm now study Android Programming on my own, i have problem of understand for this "domain name" for the package...i have refer it in developer android website..and it say "domain name of your website". So i must create my own website to create an android app or i can just create it my own without website domain name?

P/s: this question is not about how the arrangement of the package name..this is question about do i need to have website or not..thank you.Please Answer kindly^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not need to have the actual domain name registered to you and linked to a website.

However, as a general practice most people do buy the domain name, as it prevents anyone else from doing so, and they can use it as a unique identifier for their apps.

Comment: thank you for answering..
So it just mean i can have the domain or not correct..that makes it difference only to make the name is my unique..
so can i use blog?

Comment: You could use a blog, but if you're using a blogging service like blogspot, you'd end up with com.blogspot.yourblog.appname, which can get kinda long with sub packages. It would be much cleaner to just register a domain name like phoedrive.com. They're pretty cheap

Comment: oh i think it's ok for now...i will use the blog first..
but for extra information..can you recommend where can i register cheap domain?

Comment: @PhoeDrive Pretty much all sites have the same pricing. Try name.com

Comment: Oh its ok..i got it..haha..it is legit..ok thank you everybody!!